# shade hadoop in apache spark

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hadoop

We are using apache spark in standalone mode for mllib. We also have DFS(Distributed File System) which uses Hadoop 0.X.X. This conflicts due to another version of Hadoop used by apache spark.

How do I build the apache spark with shaded Hadoop?

Comment: Spark pretty heavily relies on Hadoop 2.x, and if you download it from the site, it includes it... Or you can create a shaded maven jar with whatever you want... What issues are you having?

Comment: I do not want to create a fat jar of all the 227 dependency jars. I need only the Hadoop as a shaded fat jar while the other dependencies(third party jars) need to be as an individual jar. Because we have other dependencies which will lead to conflict. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that number, because Hadoop clients don't have that many, and I doubt Spark core does either

Comment: Even if you did this successfully, though, the Namenode protocol between the Hadoop versions would be so different that I wouldn't be surprised if it did not work

Comment: For the least I should be able to shade the hadoop inside the spark. How can I do it? which pom should I modify?

Comment: You don't need to edit any Spark source code. You can create your own POM with Spark Core and Hadoop clients

Comment: can you put an example? That would be helpful

Comment: Can you share a POM that you've tried already? I don't have an example because I don't think it'll work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179612/discussion-between-santhosh-tpixler-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Even the first public release of Spark uses Hadoop 1.0.4 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/0.9.1

Comment: That is a main issue for us. our DFS is stuck with pretty older version of hadoop

Comment: Well, then I'm not sure how you plan on using Spark... Or anything that supports YARN, really